# TensorRT inference with trtexec

Tags: tensorrt

I'm currently working with TensorRT on Windows to assess the possible performance (both in terms of computational and model performance) of models given in ONNX format. Therefore, I've also been using the `--fp16` option. Now, I'd like to find out if the quantized model still performs good or if the quantization as a larger negative impact on model performance. To do so, I'd like to run inference on a bunch of test images. I've been able to convert them to a binary blob that can be loaded with `trtexec.exe`. However, I did not find an option to save the result in binary form. This is annoying since this is an Image2Image approach and I don't want to generate a .json-result file for that. Furthermore, the json-result computed with the `--exportOutput`-option contains only a single result.

Is there an option to export binary results (like reading binary inputs)? If not, what is the easiest way on Windows to do so?

Answer (score 2):

Follow this blog to install TensorRT with Command-Line Wrapper:trtexec on Ubuntu. https://medium.com/@moshiur.faisal01/install-tensorrt-with-command-line-wrapper-trtexec-on-ununtu-20-04-lts-3e44f4f36a2b

Windows doesn't officially support TensorRT.